# Irregularities in continuously unordered array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinatorics

I have an array `ar` of size n, and each number in [1:n] appears in `ar`.
`ar` is unnecessarily ordered and I want to find how many irregularities appears.
For example, if `ar = {3,1,2}` so there are 2 irregularities in `ar`: 3 appears before 1, and 3 appears before 2.

I'm sure you can do this in O(n<sup>2</sup>) but is there a better way?

Comment: Are you talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement?

Comment: @NeilEdelman no but i'm talking about a permutation that **can** have some fixed points.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Kendall tau distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance) between the array and the identity. Moreover, since all the numbers are distinct, Kendall tau is a metric between two arrays, which may be useful.

```
/* O(n^2) */
for(i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
    for(j = i + 1; j < a_size; j++) {
        if(a[i] > a[j]) irregularities++;
    }
}
```

That is, the number of inversions. One can calculate this using [merge-sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) in `O(n log n)`. [Chan2010](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1873616) gives a `O(n sqrt(log n))` based on radix-sort with tables, buckets, and a trie, and a `O(n)` approximation method.